# Where and how to create secret on embedded Linux system?

Tags: linux, password-management, openssl, embedded-system

I'm using OpenSSL on an embedded Intel Edison (Atom Platform) running an Yocto Linux. I want to store passwords with OpenSSL on the device, but I don't know after which rules I should create the passphase.

The device is a prototype for a series of devices. So the passphrase has to be created individually and automatically. What is the best strategy? Perhaps using a secret combination of hardware constants?

Comment: Keep in mind that your secret algorithm may be reverse engineered, as [happened with UPC WiFi keys](https://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2016ams/materials/D2T2%20-%20Peter%20blasty%20Geissler%20-%20Breaking%20Naive%20ESSID%20WPA2%20Key%20Generation%20Algorithms.pdf).

Comment: Yes. But how do everybody store passwords on devices? Whats the state of the art workflow?

Comment: The "state of the art workflow" is you use an HSM, or maybe as @Sjoerd said, an embedded TPM (but I know more about HSMs than I do TPMs, so I'm making an assumption there !).  Or if you don't have either HSM or TPM, then you use cloud-based HSM.  What you don't do is go trying to obfuscate it yourself on the filesystem, because you're likely to fail at that.

Answer (score 3):

The most secure way is to use a [Trusted Platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module). This is specific hardware made for storing keys and doing cryptographic operations. This is secure even against sophisticated attackers with physical access (e.g. [the FBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBI%E2%80%93Apple_encryption_dispute)), but you need specific hardware which will cost more.

Without this, attackers may just read the key from memory. In that case you may want to come up with a solution that when an attacker compromises *one* device he does not compromise *all* devices, as would be the case for example with WPA-PSKs derived from the SSID.

Another post that goes into this is [Storing a secure key in an embedded device's memory](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198274/storing-a-secure-key-in-an-embedded-devices-memory).